# First time indoor cycling (Spinning) with no fitness history?

Tags: bicycling, conditioning

Today I've enrolled myself on indoor cycling classes but I'm not sure now if that was a good idea. What I'm concerned about is if I will manage to cycle for about 50mins taking into account that I have no fitness history and my condidion is rather non existent (I do not do any sports)

What is your view? Is it all just a matter of bike adjustment to make classes more suitable for me or should I choose something different as a start?

Thank you !

Comment: If you are out of shape you may want to check with your doctor first.  Monitor your heart rate and don't exceed your target.  Set yourself up for a good experience without overdoing it so that you will enjoy the benefits and want to continue.  Have fun!

Comment: Why would you cycle indoors? If you go out with a cycle, it will be more enjoyable, and less "work".

Comment: do you have any specific reasons why you think beginning exercise would be unhealthy for you specifically?  For instance, high blood pressure, history of heart disease, old injuries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everyone has to start somewhere.  You will very quickly find out how far you can go.

Do not try and keep up with the class, but do work on keeping your legs moving as long as you can.  I.e. Do the best you can, considering the circumstances.  You will get better with practice, and have patience.

One of the things the instructor will do is suggest tension levels on the brake.  Keep your tension easier so you can make it as far through the session as you can.

Comment: I made it through the whole classes. It was really fun, plus the instructor was really encouraging and helpful :) Got some minor injury but I will participate next week for sure :D Thanks!